# Is the JHD12864E compatible with an Arduino board?

Tags: arduino, lcd

I am using a KS0108 compatible graphic LCD (JHD12864E) and I want to connect it to my Arduino Leonardo board to display some text. I searched using Google and also in the Arduino forum but I didn’t get much information. The examples I found were for a 16*2 LCD. Please suggest connections and a basic program for an Arduino board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link for Mega2560. Check this link below which has the schematic and sample program. Arduino Leonardo board is not supported since it has less memory space.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/GLCDks0108

Also a google projects page

http://code.google.com/p/glcd-arduino/

Comment: can u plz suggest me 128*64 lcd display which is compatible with arduino leonardo?

Comment: It is not the fact that Leonardo can never communicate to the LCD (JHD12864E). It can. You have to write your own code to drive the LCD. Use the link in the Arduino page to get a rough idea about the circuit diagram. The GLCD software is very powerful which can display lots of different graphics. But after compiling the size would be so large that Leonardo cannot accomodate. If you need leonardo to communicate, then you have to write your own code and can only have less graphics to be displayed since Leonardo doesn't have much memory to store all the fonts.

Comment: Thanks....i will avoid this confusing stuff of writing ma own code and use 16*2 lcd whose code is already in arduino library. I dont know wchich is comaptible it will be helpful if you suggest the one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest LCD  character displays to interface to an Arduino are those which use the popular ST7066/HD44780 parallel interface chipset.

This is primarily because the Arduino IDE includes libraries for that chipset. Drivers can be written for other chipsets, but this is more work.